# TabPage doesn't persist controls added

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, tabcontrol

I develop in C# and VB.Net, so either code style is good for me to understand what i need todo.

I am dynamically building a TabControl.  In doing so i am also adding controls to the TabPages as i add them to the TabControl.  Problem is that the first tab (index 0) always loads faster than the second tab (index 1).

Here is the code that i use to build the TabControl:

```
tabFranchises = New TabControl  //Initialize a fresh new TabControl object
tabFranchises.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

Dim tbp As TabPage
Dim bi As BrandInfo

//TODO: Load an individual tab for each Franchise
For Each row As FranchiseRow In dt
    tbp = New TabPage(row.nm)
    tbp.Name = "tab" & row.id
    AddHandler tbp.Enter, AddressOf TabPage_Enter       //General Method assignment to Enter Event
    //AddHandler tbp.Leave, AddressOf TabPage_Leave     //General Method assignment to Leave Event

    bi = New BrandInfo(row.id)

    tbp.Controls.Add(bi)
    tabFranchises.TabPages.Add(tbp)
Next

//Add TabControl to `pnlContent`
pnlContent.Controls.Add(tabFranchises)
```

Here is the `TabPage_Enter` method:

```
Private Sub TabPage_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    //MsgBox(CType(sender, TabPage).Name & " Enter")

    Dim tp As TabPage = CType(sender, TabPage)
    tp.Controls.Clear()

    Dim bi As New BrandInfo(CShort(Strings.Mid(tp.Name, 4)))
    tp.Controls.Add(bi)

End Sub
```

It doesnt matter what happens, every time i click from the first tab to the second tab, there is a delay of load and visual remnants of the first tab while the second tab is loading.  But when i click from the second tab to the first tab, its instantaneous with a complete reload with no "ghosting" of the second tab while the first tab is loading.

Any ideas on how to resolve the speed in loading the tabpages?

Comment: Performing your controls.clear and creating new controls in a TabPage_Enter event is questionable practice.  Depending on Strings.Mid() is also a code smell, making it hard to maintain this code in the future.  Alas, what's going on in BrandInfo()?  If accessing a database the first time, you could be seeing that initial database hit taking place.

Comment: @LarsTech Code smell on `Strings.Mid()`?  Funny cause that has been the VB practice since at least QBasic, if not VB5.  As i know the first 3 characters of the TabPage name will always be `tab`, its what follows that i need.

Comment: @LarsTech How is clearing the TabPage controls content a questionable practice when i want a full refresh of all items not just a portion of the controls?

Comment: @LarsTech BrandInfo is a UserControl that works fine when there is only 1 FranchiseRow, as i have tested it and works wonderfully.  So its not any of the content on the pages, its the TabControl.  I just dont know enough about it to know where the problem is.  To verify, when i extract the content of the TabPages, they work properly, its the transition from Tab1 to Tab2 is where there is a load time, but when i go from Tab2 to Tab1, there is no load time at all.

Comment: .Net is not VB6 nor QBasic.  The questionable practice was in regards to the "enter" event.  That's an odd event to do what you are doing.  Also, clearing controls does not dispose them, you are leaking memory there.  You have to explicitly dispose the controls you are trying to clear.

Comment: @LarsTech what other event should i use to do the loading?  Enter was the only one that didnt involve clicking the body of the Tab.  Didnt see a TabChange event, but may have looked over it.

Comment: @LarsTech i had played with doing Leave, to purge controls from the collection but was trying to reduce potential slow downs so removed it for the time.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your code.  You already add this BI object to every TabPage when you create the TabControl, why are you doing it again in the Enter event?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23379/discussion-between-goldbishop-and-larstech)